# How to set INCLUDE_PATH variable to PHPUnit libraries under Composer directory for Behat

Tags: php, behat

I have some test under features directory. But when I try to run `behat` I get the following error:

```
$ ls
behat.yml  features

$ behat
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in $HOME/workspace/ums/api/trunk/tests/functional/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 24
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in $HOME/workspace/ums/api/trunk/tests/functional/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 24
```

Since PHPUnit is no longer available to install using PEAR, I finally use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). So have my PHPUnit libraries installed under

```
$ sudo find / -name  PHPUnit
/HOME/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit
/HOME/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/PHPUnit
/tmp/ZendFramework-1.11.0/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit
/tmp/ZendFramework-1.11.0/tests/Zend/Test/PHPUnit
/usr/share/php/Zend/Test/PHPUnit
/usr/share/php/Zend-2.0/Test/PHPUnit
```

Which is the best way to set `include_path` without changing `php.ini` file and not use `set_include_path()` method in each `FeatureContext.php` example type class ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error using phpunit along with Behat, I did manage to overcome it with the following code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';
```

Given that the 'bootstrap' folder is only one two folders away from the root of the project. Hopes it helps.

Usually I have PHPUnit installed globally (via composer) on my dev and test (CI server) machines so I wont run into any trouble when running the tests. Also, in order to have the auto completion properly working of my favorite IDE (PhpStorm) I include the library in the composer.json of the project as a dev requirement. In the case of a project that uses Behat and is developed by a team the best way is to include it in the project so no developer would run into trouble when running the test.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the autoloader that comes with composer. Try adding

```
require_once 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php'
```

before using PHPUnit